Error: read ECONNRESET when trying to “strapi export” from EC2 instance with S3 as Upload Provider
I have a strapi project running on a t2.small EC2 instance, i didn’t use RDS the entire MySQL db is on the same EC2 instance along with all the strapi files.
nginx is setup on the instance too as a reverse proxy. S3 is setup as the upload provider for all media. Now i an error i cant figure out how to deal with and a couple questions on how my setup works.
My main problem is whenever i run:
npm run strapi export -- --file *file-name* --no-encrypt
I get this error
> soad-admin@0.1.0 strapi
> strapi export --file May-1-SoADBackup --no-encrypt

(node:140182) Warning: Credentials passed directly to s3Options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please wrap them inside a credentials object.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
Starting export...
✔ schemas: 20 transfered (size: 25.4 KB) (elapsed: 39 ms) 
✔ entities: 689 transfered (size: 356.7 KB) (elapsed: 297 ms) 
⠴ assets: 232 transfered (size: 558.7 MB) (elapsed: 96308 ms) (5.8 MB/s)node:events:496
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:217:20)
Emitted 'error' event on PassThrough instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:169:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:128:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  errno: -104,
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read'
}

Node.js v20.11.1

From everything ive seen ECONNRESET is related to network timing out but the last time i ran the same command there were no issues and i changed no configs since. Similar threads pointed out the issue could be in my nginx.conf so i made these changes to that, still the same problem
# nginx.conf

server {
  sendfile off;
  ...
  proxy_buffering off;
  ...
}

Not sure what to do here and quite honestly don’t understand strapi’s architecture enough to debug it myself.
Thank you in advance!
